# Issue with emgucv C# and Capture

Tags: c#, opencv, capture, emgucv

I am having an issue with a System.StackOverflowException with the Capture function. Here is the code, please ignore the loadScript function but take a look at the constructor and FaceDetect function:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Emgu.CV;
    using Emgu.CV.Structure;
    using Emgu.Util;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using PAD_SCRIPT;
    using Emgu.CV.GPU;
    using Emgu.CV.UI;



    namespace PAD_CORE_ENGINE
    {
        class VisionCore
        {
             private Capture capture;
             private HaarCascade haarCascade;

             double[,] faceData = new double[100, 5];
             double[,] eyeData = new double[100, 10];
             double[,] circleData = new double[100, 5];

             int numberOfFaces;
             private Image<Bgr, Byte> image;
             private System.Windows.Forms.Timer myTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

             public VisionCore()
             {

                 capture = new Capture(0);
                 capture.ImageGrabbed += updateFaceDetect;
                 capture.Start();
                 //haarCascade = new HaarCascade(@"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
           }

           public double[,] getDetectFaceInfo()
           {
                return faceData;
           }

           public double[,] getEyeInfo()
           {
               return eyeData;
           }

           public double[,] getCircleData()
           {
               return circleData;
           }

           public double getDetectFaceX(int index)
           {
               return faceData[index, 0];
           }

           public double getDetectFaceY(int index)
           {
              return faceData[index, 1];
           }

           public double getDetectFaceWidth(int index)
           {
              return faceData[index, 2];
           }

           public double getDetectFaceHeight(int index)
           {
              return faceData[index, 3];
           }

           public double getEyeX(int index)
           {
              return eyeData[index, 0];
           }

           public double getEyeY(int index)
           {
              return eyeData[index, 1];
           }

           public double getEyeWidth(int index)
           {
              return eyeData[index, 2];
           }

           public double getEyeHeight(int index)
           {
              return eyeData[index, 3];
           }



           private void DetectFace(Image<Bgr, Byte> image, String faceFileName, String eyeFileName, List<Rectangle> faces, List<Rectangle> eyes, out long detectionTime)
           {

               Stopwatch watch;

               if (GpuInvoke.HasCuda)
               {
                    using (GpuCascadeClassifier face = new GpuCascadeClassifier(faceFileName))
                    using (GpuCascadeClassifier eye = new GpuCascadeClassifier(eyeFileName))
                    {
                        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        using (GpuImage<Bgr, Byte> gpuImage = new GpuImage<Bgr, byte>(image))
                        using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> gpuGray = gpuImage.Convert<Gray, Byte>())
                        {
                             Rectangle[] faceRegion = face.DetectMultiScale(gpuGray, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);
                             faces.AddRange(faceRegion);
                             foreach (Rectangle f in faceRegion)
                             {
                                 using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> faceImg = gpuGray.GetSubRect(f))
                                 {
                                     //For some reason a clone is required.
                                     //Might be a bug of GpuCascadeClassifier in opencv
                                     using (GpuImage<Gray, Byte> clone = faceImg.Clone(null))
                                     {
                                          Rectangle[] eyeRegion = eye.DetectMultiScale(clone, 1.1, 10, Size.Empty);

                                          foreach (Rectangle e in eyeRegion)
                                          {
                                               Rectangle eyeRect = e;
                                               eyeRect.Offset(f.X, f.Y);
                                               eyes.Add(eyeRect);
                                          }
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                         watch.Stop();
                     }

                 }
                 else
                 {
                    //Read the HaarCascade objects
                    using (CascadeClassifier face = new CascadeClassifier(faceFileName))
                    using (CascadeClassifier eye = new CascadeClassifier(eyeFileName))
                    {
                         watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                         using (Image<Gray, Byte> gray = image.Convert<Gray, Byte>()) //Convert it to Grayscale
                         {
                             //normalizes brightness and increases contrast of the image
                             gray._EqualizeHist();

                             //Detect the faces  from the gray scale image and store the locations as rectangle
                             //The first dimensional is the channel
                             //The second dimension is the index of the rectangle in the specific channel
                             Rectangle[] facesDetected = face.DetectMultiScale(
                             gray,
                             1.1,
                             10,
                             new Size(20, 20),
                             Size.Empty);
                             faces.AddRange(facesDetected);

                             foreach (Rectangle f in facesDetected)
                             {
                                  //Set the region of interest on the faces
                                  gray.ROI = f;
                                  Rectangle[] eyesDetected = eye.DetectMultiScale(
                                  gray,
                                  1.1,
                                  10,
                                  new Size(20, 20),
                                  Size.Empty);
                                  gray.ROI = Rectangle.Empty;

                                  foreach (Rectangle e in eyesDetected)
                                  {
                                       Rectangle eyeRect = e;
                                       eyeRect.Offset(f.X, f.Y);
                                       eyes.Add(eyeRect);
                                  }
                             }
                        }
                        watch.Stop();
                   }

                }
                detectionTime = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                capture.QueryFrame();

            }


            protected void updateFaceDetect(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                 //Image<Bgr, Byte> image, String faceFileName, String eyeFileName, List<Rectangle> faces, List<Rectangle> eyes, out long detectionTime

                 Image<Bgr, Byte> image = capture.RetrieveBgrFrame();
                 string faceFileName = "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml";
                 string eyeFileName = "haarcascade_eye.xml";
                 List<Rectangle> faces = new List<Rectangle>();
                 List<Rectangle> eyes = new List<Rectangle>();
                 long detectionTime = 0;
                 DetectFace(image, faceFileName, eyeFileName, faces, eyes, out detectionTime);
                 DisplayImage(image);
             }

             public Image<Bgr, Byte> getImage()
             {
                 return image;
             }

             public void DisplayImage(Image<Bgr, Byte> img)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     ImageViewer.Show(image, String.Format(
                     "Completed face and eye detection using {0}",
                     GpuInvoke.HasCuda ? "GPU" : "CPU"
                     ));
        }
        catch (Exception i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i.Message);
        }
    }

    public Image<Bgr, Byte> processFaces(Image<Bgr, Byte> img, List<Rectangle> faces)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle face in faces)
            img.Draw(face, new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

        return img;
    }

    public Image<Bgr, Byte> processEyes(Image<Bgr, Byte> img, List<Rectangle> eyes)
    {
        foreach (Rectangle eye in eyes)
            img.Draw(eye, new Bgr(Color.Blue), 2);

        return img;
    }

    public void testVision()
    {
        DisplayImage(capture.RetrieveBgrFrame());
    }

    public CircleF[] detectCircles(Image<Bgr, Byte> img)
    {
        Image<Gray, Byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, Byte>().PyrDown().PyrUp();
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        double cannyThreshold = 180.0;
        double circleAccumulatorThreshold = 120;
        CircleF[] circles = gray.HoughCircles(new Gray(cannyThreshold), new Gray(circleAccumulatorThreshold), 2.0, 20.0, 5, 0)[0];
        watch.Stop();
        return circles;
    }

    public Image<Bgr, Byte> ProcessCircles(Image<Bgr, Byte> img, CircleF[] circles)
    {
        foreach (CircleF circle in circles)
        {
            img.Draw(circle, new Bgr(Color.Brown), 2);
        }

        return img;
    }

    //display the image 


    public int getNumOfFaces()
    {
        return numberOfFaces;
    }

    public PADScript loadScript(PADScript l)
    {
        l.addLuaCommand("getNumOfFaces", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceInfo", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getImage", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceInfo", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getEyeInfo", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceX", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceY", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceWidth", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getDetectFaceHeight", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getEyeX", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getEyeY", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getEyeWidth", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("getEyeHeight", this);
        l.addLuaCommand("testVision", this);

        return l;
    }
}
```

}

I am thinking that the capture is querying too many captures at once, but I also get the error in using (GpuCascadeClassifier face = new GpuCascadeClassifier(faceFileName)). I am not really for sure where this error is coming from. Thank you in advance for your help!

Edit: the exception is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Emgu.CV.GPU.dll

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: @marol the exception is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Emgu.CV.GPU.dll